# In Grails, how can I get the request URI including request parameters?

Tags: grails, groovy, httprequest

If my incoming URL is this....

```
http://data-api:8080/policies/400?output=json
```

...what method on the request object in Grails will give me this...

```
/policies/400?output=json
```

I know `request.forwardURI` gives everything up to ?, but does not include the parameters

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
request.requestURI + '?' + request.queryString
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the difference of `request.requestURI` between in Jetty and in WebLogic 10.2.

So, I use helper class :

```
def helper = new org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper()
def reqURI = helper.getOriginatingRequestUri(request)
def qryStr = helper.getOriginatingQueryString(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

it's maybe not the best solution, but I use the following:

```
request.forwardURI+'?'+request.'javax.servlet.forward.query_string'
```