# Grails request object null in Jetty 8.1

Tags: grails, groovy, jetty, httprequest

The following code works as expected on Grails 2.0.4 and Eclipse STS 3.2 using Eclipse's embedded tcServer 2.7 as the web container...

```
class TestController {

    def service() {
      println request.request.getRequestURL()
      //render response here...
    }
```

For a client request of `http://svr1:8080/testapp/test/node1`, the above code prints the full request URL, `http://svr1:8080/testapp/test/node1`.

We created a WAR and deployed it to Jetty 8.1.10, but found that `request.request` returns null, so the above code fails with a null pointer. We tried using `request.getRequestURL()` but it returns a URL containing grails dispatch syntax, so it does not match the original client request url which is what we need.

As a workaround, we manually constructed most of the URL using `request.getServerName()`, `request.getServerPort()`, and `request.getContextPath()`,  giving `http://svr1:8080/testapp`, but that still leaves out the uri portion, `/test/node1`. We assume this problem may be attributed to Jetty's Servlet API implementation, but if that were the case surely someone else would have picked up on this before us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround that appears to work on tcServer and Jetty posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8611398/791406). We construct the base URL manually, then use this utility to get the remaining portion.